# Proper way of returning array and checking if not nil

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I've encountered problem while learning Swift. I've got class with couple of variables which are fine but I wanted to return the array of [CGColor] to make different background gradient in UIView.

part of the code:

```
class Xxx{
    var _output : String!
    var _backgroundGradient : [CGColor]!

    //checking if not nil
    var output : String!{
        if _output == nil{
            _output = ""
        }
        return _output
    }

var backgroundGradient : [CGColor]{
    if _backgroundGradient?.isEmpty == false{
        print("There are objects!")
    } else{
        print("There are no objects")
        _backgroundGradient = [CGColor]()
    }
    return _backgroundGradient
}
```

So as you can see the _output is ok, if it's nil then I assign the empty String. I've tried to do similar thing with array, if it's empty then create empty array but not nil

further in the code there is function which appends certain value:

```
(...)
     self._backgroundGradient.append(UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.79, blue:0.04, alpha:1.00).cgColor)
     self._backgroundGradient.append(UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.41, blue:0.02, alpha:1.00).cgColor)
     print("GRADIENT inside func -> \(self._backgroundGradient)")
(...)
```

and as I can see in the bottom console of Xcode it's displayed properly:

```
GRADIENT inside func -> Optional([<CGColor 0x6000000b1340> [<CGColorSpace 0x6000000359e0> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1; extended range)] ( 1 0.79 0.04 1 ), <CGColor 0x6080000b15e0> [<CGColorSpace 0x6000000359e0> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1; extended range)] ( 0.97 0.41 0.02 1 )])
```

In my main ViewController file in viewDidLoad() when I try to assign the backgroundGradient from xxx class there is a problem:

```
(...)
var classXxx : Xxx!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        classXxx = Xxx()

        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

        gradient.colors = classXxx.backgroundGradient
        print("MainVC GRADIENT -> \(gradient.colors)")
(...)
```

and the console's output:

```
MainVC GRADIENT -> Optional([])
```

The problem must be return in var backgroundGradient. Every other variable like string, int and so on works like a charm, the array is a problem.

Comment: When you do `Xxx()` you are creating a new instance of your class with it's own array that starts out empty.

Comment: @dan so Xxx() creates backgroundGradient array which is empty? But can I retrieve backgroundGradient without creating classXxx = Xxx()? Could you help and solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not calling the function which adds the colors to the backgroundGradient array.

You need to change this code snippet to make the function call after you create the Xxx object.

```
(...)
var classXxx : Xxx!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        classXxx = Xxx()

        // Call function to add colors to the backgroundGradient array
        classXxx.addColors() // Change 'addColors()' to the name of the function which contains the lines of code quoted below

        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

        gradient.colors = classXxx.backgroundGradient
        print("MainVC GRADIENT -> \(gradient.colors)")
(...)
```

--

```
func addColors() {
    (...)
         self._backgroundGradient.append(UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.79, blue:0.04, alpha:1.00).cgColor)
         self._backgroundGradient.append(UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.41, blue:0.02, alpha:1.00).cgColor)
         print("GRADIENT inside func -> \(self._backgroundGradient)")
    (...)
}
```

--

EDIT:

You can simplify your class by initializing your variables with the default values.

For example:

```
class Xxx {
    var output : String = ""
    var backgroundGradient : [CGColor] = [
        UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.79, blue:0.04, alpha:1.00).cgColor,
        UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.41, blue:0.02, alpha:1.00).cgColor
    ]
}
```

Comment: Oh god, so it means that the only thing that I did wrong was calling the function in wrong place. It's working now but is there maybe a better way to do it? Thanks for help!

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want. Do you want the classXxx to always start of with having those two colors?